# provide self computing power to a specific selected contract transactions

Tags: contract-development, gas, enterprise

I'm reading about smart contract, but not sure how a developers can:

- provide computer power for its own contract
- and/or accelerate that contract transactions on the network.

#### Current Possible Solution A

If I have a smart contract, and wants to provide users of that contact to be able to run it functions ***without paying gas***, I thought of one solution for now:

- Provide a web interface
- which talk to my proxy node,
- and in turns talk to  and my own Ethereum node.

The users on the frontend activate transactions, but actually the proxy node dispatch the transaction with my main identity/wallet stored on that node which pay the gas.

##### Solution A Disadvantage

That solution still needs the interested party - the author - to buy ether and use ether to accelerate its contract transactions.

#### Question - A Way to Provide Raw Computer Power

Is there a way instead of ether/money, to provide the raw computing power - meaning to create an Ethereum node, connect it to the mainnet, and configure that node to:

1. Accept only my specific contract transactions for mining
2. Forgo the gas fee, or lower it to negligible amount for my specific contract only

That way, the private node computing power is payed by me regularly on aws/gce ... and I will not need ether to provide the computing power.

Comment: By mining blocks you'll be competing against mainnet miners so you'll need a lot of computing resources to have a decent block mining rate. Some games have opted to create their own sidechain, they mine blocks but they don't have to compete against mainnet miners.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for the time to answer. Does it mean the "bottleneck" is that even if I configure a ethereum client to process my transactions for free, in order to enter those transactions results to the mainnet, the power needed for the pow for getting the publish rights from the consensus, is whats i can not remove?

Comment: Yes. In a PoW blockchain you'll be competing against existing miners, if your hardware isn't very capable you might not be able to publish blocks. You might offset some of the cost with the block reward, but at that point probably it is a better business to be just a miner.